# How to make TCP enabled on lan

Tags: wpf, wcf, service

I have written a code for my WPF App to use WCF, wcf is running as Windows service, I want the program wpf to run on client machines.  I installed WPF app on PC along with the service and sql server, it is working fine in there.  However, when I installed the wpf client on another PC, the client WPF is not able to connect to the server. I mean the WCF windows service is not support for lan usage, however I designed it for this intention only.  Could you please check my code and tell me where I have gone wrong please.

WPF App code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WorkMateWPF.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFBatchImport" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFCourses" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFFaculty" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFLogin" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFStudent" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFBatchImports"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IWCFBatchImport"
                contract="ServiceBatchImports.IWCFBatchImport" name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFBatchImport">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFCourses" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IWCFCourses" contract="ServiceCourses.IWCFCourses"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFCourses">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFFaculty" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IWCFFaculty" contract="ServiceFaculty.IWCFFaculty"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFFaculty">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFLogin" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IWCFLogin" contract="ServiceLogins.IWCFLogin"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFLogin">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFStudents" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IWCFStudent" contract="ServiceStudents.IWCFStudent"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IWCFStudent">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <userSettings>
        <WorkMateWPF.MySettings>
            <setting name="Test" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </WorkMateWPF.MySettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Following is the service app code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WorkMateWCF.My.MySettings.workmateConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=PAVAN-PC;Initial Catalog=WorkMate;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=WorkMateUser;Password=workmateuser"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.WCFLogin">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.IWCFLogin">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFLogin" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.WCFCourses">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.IWCFCourses">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFCourses" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.WCFStudent">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.IWCFStudent">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFStudents" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.WCFBatchImport">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.IWCFBatchImport">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFBatchImports" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.WCFFaculty">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.IWCFFaculty">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFFaculty" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Looking forward for the needfull.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later checked the event logs and the issue was with the time on binding and I changed it to 00:10:00 and it seems to work, but this time I landed on a new error and it does not relate to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that all of your service addresses are set to localhost, in both the service and the client config files.  Localhost always refers to the machine the program is running on.

You'll need to use the correct machine name for the service and reference it in the client.

For example, say your service is hosted on a machine on the network with the following address - myservicebox:8732.  The service's config file would look like this:

```
<service name="WorkMateWCF.WCFLogin">
  <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            contract="WorkMateWCF.IWCFLogin">
    <identity>
      <dns value="myservicebox" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://myservicbox:8732/WCFLogin" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

You would then reference `net.tcp://myservicebox:8732/WCFLogin` in your client(s) that wish to utilize the service.

Also, note that your service (based on your posted config file) will be using the default values for the specified bindings, which may cause problems for you if you need different values (like bigger message size, etc).

Your client config will use the bindings you've set up as you assign them to the client endpoints via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute.

Not necessarily a problem in your case (and it looks like you're using the default values on the client anyway, at a quick glance), but something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Am I required to host this in any manner?  I had installed this by using windows service project.  Waiting for your reply.  Thanks

Comment: Hosting your WCF service in a Windows Service is fine - it all depends on your needs and requirements (you can also self-host and host under IIS/WAS).  I generally use IIS, but I have one service at work that is hosted in a Windows Service.

Comment: I tried by changing the name of localhost to pc name, however, now thye app is not working on its own pc also.  Is there any thing wrong by simple replacement.  My program is only for the small network on 10-15 pcs only, not on internet. Looking forward.

Comment: Hmm...you might want to try the machine's IP address instead.  Don't forget the port - for example, `net.tcp://192.168.1.1:8732/WCFLogin`.  Just replace 192.168.1.1 with whatever the IP address of the machine the service is on is.

Comment: Not sure on that one - I'd have to check.  For testing purposes, I'd simply remove the DNS value tag and see if it works.

Comment: It is not working both ways, could you please help me with it, I can upload the solution to you, could you please modify/test, this one is eating my brain from a long time, I have completed the program however, it is not working on lan.  Could you please do the need?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4304/discussion-between-surpavan-and-tim)